# Separate data from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

The desire here is to print a single attribute from the CLBeacon property instead of the debug string which is able to be generated as below, but the compiler doesn't understand because it's not cast to the right type.

Here is the code I'm using

```
for(NSString *beacon in [self->detectBeacons allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"Här ska det visas lite data: %@",[self->detectBeacons objectForKey:beacon]);
}
```

and its generating this line

```
("CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x14de6e060> FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825, major:10004, minor:57607, proximity:1 +/- 0.01m, rssi:-28)",
"CLBeacon (uuid:<__NSConcreteUUID 0x14de02310> FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825, major:10004, minor:54480, proximity:1 +/- 0.01m, rssi:-31)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the desire here is to access a single property rather than print the whole debug string.

More efficient is to use `[self->detectBeacons allValues]`

The problem is your item are not casted in the dictionary.
Cast it to CLBeacon and access the proximityUUID property.

```
NSLog("proximityUUID: %@",((CLBeacon*)[self->detectBeacons objectForKey:beacon]). proximityUUID );
```

Or in your case the first object, it's not clear but your item was an array.

```
NSLog("proximityUUID: %@",((CLBeacon*)[ [self->detectBeacons objectForKey:beacon]) firstObject].proximityUUID );
```

Comment: I want to get the values in there own variables or lines in the log, like the rssi with its own variable/line etc

Comment: Try debugDescription. Does this generate desirable output?

Comment: no, i don't think you understand what i mean, sorry

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems you might be having some trouble describing it in English. Please try again.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to READ them from the LOG?

Comment: You don't need to give a negative??

Comment: I want to read a specific attribute from the line it generates. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. How do you have access to the line, are you reading console logs in an application or script.

Comment: I show the line in the log by the code i have submitted. I have also provided what the output is on the log. But i wonder if there is a way where i can select a single attribute and show it.

Comment: NSLog("myAttribute: %@",[self->detectBeacons objectForKey:beacon].myAttribute ) ?

Comment: Don't you think i tried it? I get this error, very frustrating `AppDelegate.m:43:93: Property 'proximityUUID' not found on object of type 'id _Nullable'`

Comment: How about `NSLog("proximityUUID: %@",((CLBeacon*)[self->detectBeacons objectForKey:beacon]). proximityUUID );`. proximityUUID is a publicly exposed attribute of CLBeacon, once the correct type is known via cast.

Comment: I get this error now `[__NSArrayI proximityUUID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12e502170`

Comment: So it's an array. That is unusual try accessing the first element. `NSLog("proximityUUID: %@",((CLBeacon*)[[self->detectBeacons objectForKey:beacon] objectAtIndex:0]). proximityUUID );` You're not storing an array of beacons for each Id are you?

Comment: In light of this I've changed the answer to be succinct and clear, please accept it to let other uses know what solved the problem